# How create a django model to filter by a foreign key field

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models which are connected by a foreign key.

```
Book
 isbn - this is a unique value

Order
 book_isbn - this should refer to Book's isbn above.
```

1. How to introduce Order model the isbn of the Book as a foreign key.
2. I want to query orders which have given isbn (i.e. filter Order objects where **book_isbn = given_isbn** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do models like,

```
class Book(models.Model):
    isbn = models.CharField(unique=True, primary_key=True, max_length=5)
    #some fields....

class Order(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, related_name='orders')
    #another fields..
```

Then you could do the queries like,

```
given_isbn = 'some_value'
items = Order.objects.filter(book=given_isbn)
```

Or for a given book instances,

```
orders = book.orders.all()
```

**EDIT**

Or you could remove `primary_key=True` from Book model isbn field and do
the queries like,

```
items = Order.objects.filter(book__isbn=given_isbn)
```

Then, Django provides an automatic incrementing primary key for each object instances.

Comment: Is the related_name is essential? Can I directly use the filter query as Order.objects.filter(book=<given_isbn>)

Comment: Related name is for making reverse queries more readable... dont worry about it...... Yes, you can query order objects like that...

Comment: I prefer the last solution because it don't change the auto id given by django. It worked when I refer with book__isbn=given_isbn. (two underscores)

Comment: sorry it was my mistake

Comment: Could you then do me a favour and mark the answer as selected, then?

Answer (score 0):

Models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
     isbn = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=5)

class Order(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    #another fields..
```

Get your desired book.

```
book = Book.objects.get(isbn=isbn)
```

get relevant orders of books.

```
orders = book.order_set.all()
```

It will return all orders of particular book.

Another approach: Simple filter all records by filter query.

```
order_qs = Order.objects.filter(book=book)
```

thank you.